# How to embed multiple XtraReports into Outlook email body?

Tags: c#, xaf

There are multiple reports in the DevExpress-based (Xaf) windows application.

By request I have to get selected reports from the application, generate these reports, then create an email in outlook application and embed these reports to the email html body.

The question is: if I have a `XtraReport` class instance, and I have `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem` class instance. How can I embed report to the email html body?

```
XtraReport xtraReport = reportContainer.Report;
xtraReport.CreateDocument();

MailItem email = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)(oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
```

I want to embed `xtraReport`object to the `email` html body, but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the XtraReports export-functions. I'd probably go with [XtraReport.ExportToHTML(Stream stream)](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport.ExportToHtml.method(QnK3hQ)) and then simply write the stream
back into the mails HTML-body.
Something like this (untested):

```
            report.CreateDocument();
            string reportHtml = String.Empty;

            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                report.ExportToHtml(stream);
                stream.Position = 0;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    reportHtml = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            mailItem.Body = reportHtml;
```